How to deliver Django+ NextJs+ Postgresql project to client
I have my backend built on django and frontend on nextjs. I have to deliver it to client but I don't know how to do it. I have env folder in my django root directory which is virtual environment and I have made a requirements.txt file in the root of django project as well with .env file for secret keys. Also I have a folder named backend which contains tha next js project. It has package-json file in it. Do I have to make gitignore files in both directories if I am making the github push. And how can I deliver the project to the client I am a beginner.
I tried transferring my virtual environment folder along with my project of django but the virtual environment didn't work correctly because it had directories with paths of my personal computer. What should I do...
